# Having issue determining credentials used when connecting to SoftLayer ObjectStorage using SFTP

Tags: ibm-cloud, sftp, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, object-storage

I'm having trouble connecting to the Bluemix Object Store using the instructions presented by this link: https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/connect-object-storage-using-sftp

It's unclear to me what the username and account ID are so I would appreciate it if someone can clarify

1. The instructions are valid
2. Where I can find the values for SLOS/IBMOS etc?

I do not have access to the Softlayer customer portal as this service as created in Bluemix.

I can confirm that an sftp server is listening at the appropriate region  endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Brien, it is not possible to use SFTP to access the Bluemix Object Storage if you create it from the Services catalog area of the Bluemix UI:

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/object-storage

This one can be accessed via swift cli or REST API.

To use SFTP to access your Object Storage you need to create it from the Infrastructure are of the Bluemix UI - that is the legacy Softayer that is now integrated with Bluemix.

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/infrastructure/object_storage/

Also, to create the Object Storage from the Infrastructure catalog you need to first link your Bluemix and Softlayer accounts:

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/admin/softlayerlink.html

Comment: I'm sorry but those instructions do not appear to be for sftp client access e.g. linux sftp, putty sftp etc.  Thanks

Comment: can you confirm you created a Bluemix Object Storage? ie. from here https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/?taxonomyNavigation=apps&category=storage? There are a couple of other options under infrastructure, so I just want to make sure you have create the Bluemix one

Comment: Yes. I can confirm that I created a Bluemix Object Storage Services from the Services category.  Thanks for your help.